# MYSQL INSERT INTO WITH SELECT not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to do a insert into a with SELECT, bit this following query doesnt seems to be working for some reason,

```
INSERT INTO `employer_data` 
(`employer_id`, `data`, `datetime`) 
VALUES 
( SELECT employer_id, employer_id AS data, NOW() AS `datetime` FROM employer );
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: FYI ~ you don't need to alias the columns in the `SELECT` query. The names are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `values` keyword

```
INSERT INTO `employer_data` 
(`employer_id`, `data`, `datetime`)  
( SELECT employer_id, employer_id AS data, NOW() AS `datetime` FROM employer );
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax was wrong.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `employer_data` 
(`employer_id`, `data`, `datetime`) 
SELECT employer_id, employer_id AS data, NOW() AS `datetime` FROM employer;
```

**Refer To**:
[MySQL: INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)